# Combining a list and int when writing a csv row

Tags: django

I have three variables:

```
a = 3
b = 1
c = [4, 1, 4]
```

I want to write these to one row in a csv file to get the following output:

```
3,1,4,1,4
```

Here's my code so far:

```
with open('results.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    results_writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    results_writer.writerow(XXX)
```

**What goes in place of XXX?**

My attempts so far are:

```
XXX = [a, b], c
```

which gives the error:

```
TypeError: writerow() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

And:

```
XXX = [a, b, c]
```

which gives the following (undesired) output:

```
3,1,"[1, 4, 1]"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
results_writer.writerow([a, b] + c)
```